In sql Not able get the column data with lookup table Postgresql
I have two tables, Customer table and a lookup table which in customer table has 3 columns and lookup table has 2 columns (which is like vlookup in Excel). Every detailed information is in the lookup table. I want to get detailed information match with customer table.
Customer table:



Custo ID
name
address




1
1
6


2
4
6


3
4
7


4
3
8


5
2
7



Lookup table:



lk_id
lk_value




1
A


2
B


3
C


4
D


5
E


6
x


7
y


8
z



How can I get the output like this:



name
address




A
x


C
z



I tried this query
Select 
    name, address 
from 
    customer, lookup 
where 
    lk_id = name 
    and lk_id = address

But I am getting only first column in where condition, how can I get address column?

Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - that old-style comma-separated list of tables style was replaced with the proper ANSI JOIN syntax in the ANSI-92 SQL Standard (more than 30 years ago!) and its use is discouraged

@marc_s: Your comment is simply wrong. Nothing was "replaced". Explicit join syntax is typically easier to read and generally advisable. But commas in the FROM list are legit as ever. Explicit joins also bind stronger, so not 100 % equivalent. Commas are not discouraged in Postgres. Don't sell your personal opinion as fake fact.

Please update the post with the DDL for each table, including indexes and constraints. Without those details, it's possible to craft queries that will produce the desired results for the example data, but those queries might not be correct for all possible valid data.

You can use two joins, one on the name and one on the address
SELECT n.lk_value AS name, a.lk_value AS address
FROM   customer c
JOIN   lookup n ON c.name = n.lk_id
JOIN   lookup a ON c.address = a.lk_id

EDIT:
As JohnH mentioned in the comments, this query assumes that every customer has valid name and address entries. If this isn't the case, you should use outer joins instead:
SELECT    n.lk_value AS name, a.lk_value AS address
FROM      customer c
LEFT JOIN lookup n ON c.name = n.lk_id
LEFT JOIN lookup a ON c.address = a.lk_id


This query works for the example data; however, the OP didn't include a description of the constraints, so it's possible that either name or address could be NULL. If NULL is allowed (or if there's no corresponding foreign key constraint to enforce data integrity), then JOIN should be replaced with LEFT OUTER JOIN.

@JohnH good point, thanks! From the OP I assumed this wasn't possible, but it's probably worth mentioning. I edited this into my answer (with attribution, of course)

Great ! Thank you it gave the output what I want..

@Mureinik, it's all to easy to make assumptions based on the conventions that one normally follows. Given the OP's use of a generic lookup table for unrelated values (which I consider to be an anti-pattern) and the attributes name and address instead of name_id and address_id, I'm hesitant to assume any unspecified constraints.
